# Android Better UI Design

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I've just recently started getting into Android development, and know about all the basic features of it such as permissions, basic UI, adapters, activities and interacting with a backend. How do I proceed if I want to further develop my UI/UX skills? Apps like Instagram and twitter have an interactive and attractive layout involving user inputs such as swipe. What's a good place to start to get more familiar with fancy layouts that are favourable to users?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: use material library for better ui designing. here you can start http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/. you can also refer from material docs from android official. this may help you for starting your android development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 topics being discussed here: **design** and **implementation**.

Design includes UI/UX, interaction & motion.. You can find more types of design in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738445/2475185).

Implementation is a process of converting (usually) a static design to an interactive application. In your case you're doing this in Android. But the fancy layouts are general, not specific to Android.

Lastly, if you're interested in simply seeing some examples of Android UI and maybe their code, try [this github repo](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui)

Answer (score 0):

Almost everything about the layout in android is made with XML. If you want your layout to look better, you can also use different themes (either a custom one or a template one)

Editing an UI with XML also offers more possibilities than the graphical UI designer. You should get more information about designing UIs with XML on the internet.